# Saving parent/child header/line using Doctrine 1.2

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, orm, foreign-key-relationship

I have a simple parent-child/header-line model in my project. The problem is that its creating a cyclic relation or something, and not letting me save the parent without the child! Detect relations is switched off!

```
detect_relations: false
...
BillHeader:
  package: Billing
  tableName: Bill_Headers
  actAs:
    SoftDelete: ~
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      primary: true
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
    ....

BillLine:
  package: Billing
  tableName: Bill_Lines
  actAs:
    SoftDelete: ~
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      primary: true
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
    bill_header_id:
      type: integer(8)
      notnull: true
  relations:
    Bill_Header:
      class: BillHeader
      local: bill_header_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: Bill_Lines
      type: one
```

1. when I save the parent first: `$billHeader->save();` gives error: ***SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sokidb`.`bill_headers`, CONSTRAINT `Bill_Headers_id_Bill_Lines_bill_header_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `bill_lines` (`bill_header_id`))***
2. when I do `$billHeader->Bill_Lines[] = $billLine;` gives the error: ***Add is not supported for BillLine***
3. The line won't save without the parent, so I can't even do `$billHeader->link('Bill_Lines', $billLines);`
4. `$billHeader->Bill_Lines = $billLines;` gives the error ***Couldn't call Doctrine_Core::set(), second argument should be an instance of Doctrine_Collection when setting one-to-many references.***
5. If I drop the relationship, do a `$billHeader->save();`, then
   `$billHeader->id` returns empty. So thats not working either!

I wonder if there is a 6th way of doing it??? :(

I'm tired of thinking on this problem, there seems to be no solution. Almost 3 days on this and now clue! its getting me suicidal! why this behaviour? Will it help if the table is MyIsam instead of InnoDB?

Any help on this is much appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with your schema. The constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT Bill_Headers_id_Bill_Lines_bill_header_id  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES bill_lines (bill_header_id))
```

Should not exist. The id of BillHeader should not be a foreign key of BillLine. Instead, there should be a constraint from BillLine to BillHeader, something like:

```
CONSTRAINT `Bill_Lines_header_id_Bill_Header_id` FOREIGN KEY (`bill_header_id`) REFERENCES `Bill_Header` (`id`)
```

Do you have additional relations defined on BillHeader that may be adding that constraint? Regardless, the key here is to play with your schema until the constraint is going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your response Jeremy. Well, the schema is right in front of you! :) I tried defining the relation on BillHeader, but still doesn't work.
The second relation u mentioned is also getting created, but the 1st one is unexpected & creating the problem. I did try using autocomplete: false, but that doesn't seem to work either!

Comment: Yes, the key indeed is to keep playing with the Schema.

But one thing I learned is that going thru the generated SQL really helps!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it after much introspection. One of the attributes declared was marked PRIMARY. Don't know why this result, but this was the problem!